# Is there a way to add foreach loop in email template?

Tags: magento-1.7, email-templates, transactional-mail

I am trying to trigger a mail to customer after they place an order. This email will carry all the cross sell products of the products ordered.

I used the following links as reference:

[send email using event observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310894/email-notification-when-a-new-customer-has-been-added-magento)

[Advanced Transactional Email Templates](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-advanced-transactional-email-templates)

All is working well.

But now my doubt is, will I be able to use foreach loop inside the html file put inside the **locale** directory?

So that I could iterate and print all the product info in the mail template. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think that it is not possible to directly perform a foreach loop in emails, but what you could do is include a block that will do the loop in a regular template.

In you email add something like the following.

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/template.phtml' items=$items}}
```

Then in your template add the following.

```
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
    <p><?php echo $_item['name'] ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

For more information I followed this [blog](http://www.atwix.com/magento/pass-entities-collections/)

Comment: Ya I am actually was trying this. will accept this in 2 mins

Comment: Do we have to add this block inside email template? And will it understand `items=$items`? As `$items` is php variable.

Comment: Hi, I tried above not working for me. Any suggestions

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can use a for loop in emails. I've tested it on 2.3.3 version.
This is the code [location](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.3/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/Template.php#L214) to inspect.
This is how it looks like in the template:

```
<ul>
  {{for item in data.items}}
     <li>Name: {{var item.name}}</li>
  {{/for}}
</ul>
```

The transport information:

```
$this->transportBuilder->setTemplateVars(
[
 'items' => [
              ['name' => 'Product1'],
              ['name' => 'Product2']
            ]
...
```

Aside. In 2.3.4 the code was [refactored](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.4/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/Template.php#L266), but I believe it still should work as it was not removed. Please remember that Magento removed the ability to call functions on objects as of this version, so your `order->getItems()` function may not work.