# How for 'Automated Email Reminder Rules' add to email template cart items

Tags: magento-enterprise, cart

In Magento EE we have "Automated Email Reminder Rules" and standard template. I need add to template - abandonment cart items, But when magento send email (in app/code/core/Enterprise/Reminder/Model/Rule.php::sendReminderEmails (145 line)), for template set variable:

             `$templateVars = array(
                'store'          => $store,
                'coupon'         => $coupon,
                'customer'       => $customer,
                'promotion_name' => $storeData['label'],
                'promotion_description' => $storeData['description']
            );`

If i want add cart items i need rewrite this class and add to template variable cart entity?

Maybe someone will offer another solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could create a block that render the items in the shopping cart and call it in your template. 
[Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8603/7988) @David Manners explain how to do something like that

> In you email add something like the following.

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/template.phtml' items=$items}}
```

> Then in your template add the following.

```
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
     <p><?php echo $_item['name'] ?></p> <?php endforeach; ?>
```

> For more information I followed this [blog](http://www.atwix.com/magento/pass-entities-collections/)

You can pass the customer as parameter and then in the block search for the shopping cart.

Comment: How can we add the products list in abandoned cart email templates in magento EE 2.3.x ?